# Kubernetes Crashloopbackoff With Minikube

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, kubernetes

So I am learning about Kubernetes with a guide, I am trying to deploy a MongoDB Pod with 1 replica. This is the deployment config file.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb-deployment
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongodb
          image: mongo
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          env:
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-secret
                  key: mongo-root-username
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-secret
                  key: mongo-root-password
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongodb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

I also try to deploy a Mongo-Express Pod with almost the same config file, but I keep getting `CrashLoopBackOff` for both Pods, From the little understanding I have, this is caused by the container failing and restarting in a cycle. I tried going through the events with `kubectl get events` and I see that a warning with message `Back-off restarting failed container` keeps occurring. I also tried doing a little digging around and came across a solution that says to add

```
command: ['sleep']
args: ['infinity']
```

That fixed the CrashLoopBackOff issue, but when I try to get the logs for the Pod, nothing is displayed on the terminal. Please I need some help and possible explanation as how the `command` and `args` seem to fix it, also how do I stop this crash from happening to my Pods and current one, Thank you very much.

Comment: Adding the command overwrites the entry point on the container. That means that instead of running mongodb on the container, it just runs the sleep command for infinity. I assume the “solution” you found was just trying to start the container and look around. Since nothing is running on the container at that point, you get no logs.. in terms of why your pods are crashing, I would say run kubectl describe pod <podName> and kubectl logs <podName> to get more info on what is wrong

Comment: Okay, I paid attention to the logs and discovered this error ```uncaught exception: Error: couldn't add user: Error preflighting normalization: U_STRINGPREP_PROHIBITED_ERROR _getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13``` how do I fix this? I am using Windows and running minikube cluster

Comment: I was following the same tutorial but I don't understand why it does work for here but doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is to deploy MongoDB as [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) on Kubernetes.

In stateful application, the N-replicas of master nodes manages several worker nodes under a cluster. So, if any master node goes down the other ordinal instances will be active to execute the workflow. The master node instances must be identified as a unique [ordinal](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#ordinal-index) number known as StatefulSet.
See more: [mongodb-sts](https://deeptiman.medium.com/mongodb-statefulset-in-kubernetes-87c2f5974821), [mongodb-on-kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2017/01/running-mongodb-on-kubernetes-with-statefulsets/).
Also use [Headless service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) to manage the domain of a Pod. In general understanding of Headless Service, there is no need for  [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer)  or a  [*kube-proxy*](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-proxy/)  to interact directly with Pods but using a Service IP, so the Cluster IP is set to  **none**.

In your case:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: mongodb
  ports:
    - port: 27017
```

The error:

```
Also uncaught exception: Error: couldn't add user: Error preflighting normalization: U_STRINGPREP_PROHIBITED_ERROR _getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
```

indicates that the secret may be missing.  Take a look: [mongodb-initializating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58775800/error-while-initializing-user-mongodb-kubernetes).

In your case secret should look similar:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mongodb-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  mongo-root-username: YWRtaW4=
  mongo-root-password: MWYyZDFlMmU2N2Rm
```

Remember to configure also a volume for your pods - follow tutorials I have linked above.

Answer (score 1):

Try to figure out what and why it happened, run:

```
kubectl get pods
```

and after that

```
kubectl logs NAME_OF_POD_FROM_PREV_COMMAND
```

In my case the issue was "WARNING: MongoDB 5.0+ requires a CPU with AVX support, and your current system does not appear to have that!"
So I just added image version:

```
containers:
  - name: mongodb
    image: mongo:4.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Deploy mongodb with StatefulSet not as deployment.

Example:

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: mongodb-service
labels:
name: mongo
spec:
ports:

- port: 27017
  targetPort: 27017
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
  role: mongo

---

apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
name: mongod
spec:
serviceName: mongodb-service
replicas: 3
template:
metadata:
labels:
role: mongo
environment: test
replicaset: MainRepSet
spec:
affinity:
podAntiAffinity:
preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
- weight: 100
podAffinityTerm:
labelSelector:
matchExpressions:
- key: replicaset
operator: In
values:
- MainRepSet
topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
volumes:
- name: secrets-volume
secret:
secretName: shared-bootstrap-data
defaultMode: 256
containers:
- name: mongod-container
#image: pkdone/mongo-ent:3.4
image: mongo
command:
- "numactl"
- "--interleave=all"
- "mongod"
- "--wiredTigerCacheSizeGB"
- "0.1"
- "--bind_ip"
- "0.0.0.0"
- "--replSet"
- "MainRepSet"
- "--auth"
- "--clusterAuthMode"
- "keyFile"
- "--keyFile"
- "/etc/secrets-volume/internal-auth-mongodb-keyfile"
- "--setParameter"
- "authenticationMechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-1"
resources:
requests:
cpu: 0.2
memory: 200Mi
ports:
- containerPort: 27017
volumeMounts:
- name: secrets-volume
readOnly: true
mountPath: /etc/secrets-volume
- name: mongodb-persistent-storage-claim
mountPath: /data/db
volumeClaimTemplates:

- metadata:
  name: mongodb-persistent-storage-claim
  annotations:
  volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: "standard"
  spec:
  accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
  resources:
  requests:
  storage: 1Gi